# Export all offset with value of 0 on redis bitmap

Tags: redis, bitmap

For example :

```
setbit mybitmap 1 0
setbit mybitmap 2 0
setbit mybitmap 3 1
setbit mybitmap 4 0
setbit mybitmap 5 1

...

setbit mybitmap 1999998 1
setbit mybitmap 1999999 0
setbit mybitmap 2000000 1
```

Whether the value is 0 or 1 is totally random. Is there an easy way to export all offsets which has a value of 0 into a file ?

I know that I can iterate over each number from 1 to 2000000 and write it into file, but is there any simpler way to export all offsets which has a value of 0 into a file at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Redis bitmap is encoded as a string, you can simply `GET` it and process it using bit operations in your code (e.g. write to a file all offsets of zero). The serialized bitmap string's first byte corresponds to offsets 0..7 and so forth.